# JS - Document.Write issue

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use the document.write options for a website to set the recurring header that appears on every other site.
Unfortunately I'm stuck with an error cause I cant set the background-image, because it gives me an parsing error.

```
document.write('<div style="background-image: url('images/index/1ApBer2016.JPG'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;" class="header">\<h1>XXX<br> XXX</h1>\
</div>\'
          );
```

I'm thinking it's because of the quotation marks for the image itself, but I can't seem to fix it.
Do you guys have any help?

Comment: use `\`` or escape the inner `'` - also, I believe quotes in style url's are optional? try without quotes - but, number one choice is to never use document.write

Comment: You can escape a quotation mark inside a string literal by putting the escape character ```\``` before it.

Comment: Obligatory warning not to use document.write. It is almost always unnecessary, and almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, I'm just using it to not have the code for it in all the html which have the same Navbar and Header image. This way I can focus on the content itself.

Comment: Why is document.write so bad tho?

Comment: @marvin. document.write() will write your entire document. And all the old DOM elements will no longer be accesible.Will be removed with the new document.

Comment: @marvin yes Imran Rafiq Rather is correct, document.write will *overwrite* your existing HTML document (we get a lot of questions about bugs related to that).

Answer (score 1):

Escape the quotes as in the code below, using the escape character "\"

```
document.write('<div style="background-image: url(\'images/index/1ApBer2016.JPG\'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;" class="header"><h1>XXX<br> XXX</h1></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ES6 back-tics **`**. You no longer to espace any character and code looks clean and readable as well.

```
document.write(`<div style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;" class="header"><h1>XXX<br> XXX</h1>
</div>`);
```

**DEMO:**

```js
document.write(`<div style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;" class="header"><h1>XXX<br> XXX</h1>
</div>`);
```